# Button in a Listview

Tags: android

I am working with listview. I have added a Textview and button to that listview.How to know that which button is clicked.When i click that button i need to get the related text?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: please post your code..you are using Custom adapter? to populate the list view?

Answer (score 1):

see below sample code... you get idea from this..

here list_v is listview

```
list_v.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter_test(
                                this));
```

---

```
public class ListViewAdapter_test extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ListViewAdapter_test(Context con) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return a_product_id.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ListContent holder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_row1, null);
                holder = new ListContent();

                holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sc_textname);


                holder.total_rate = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (ListContent) v.getTag();
            }

            holder.name.setId(position);

            holder.total_rate.setId(position);

            holder.total_rate.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener3);

            try {

                holder.name.setText("" + a_product_name.get(position));

                holder.total_rate.setText("Read " + a_totreviews.get(position)
                        + " reviews");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception

            }

            return v;
        }
    }

    static class ListContent {



        TextView name;

        Button total_rate;

    }
```

---

```
public OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener3 = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = list_v
                    .getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());

            /** do your code here whatever you want */

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the list item click and you want to add the button, when you build the cell and add the button you can set a tag to it with button.setTag(int), you can set as tag the position of the cell, so in the click listener of the button you can retrieve the position of the button clicked with button.getTag() and you can retrieve the text if you have a data structure with the text lines inside